# How do we find the equivalent resistance in a square circuit with 4 resistors along the diagonals in the square?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

[image: The diagram]

In the given circuit diagram, if the red colored parts indicate a resistor with resistance $R_1$ along $AO$, $R_2$ along $BO$, $R_3$ along $CO$ and $R_4$ along $DO$, is there any method using which we can calculate the equivalent resistance between $A$ and $B$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all of the resistors are in parallel with each other. You can simplify the diagram using the potential method. All points with no resistance between them are at the same electric potential i.e A,B,C & D are at the same potential. Similarly, all resistors are connected to point 0, and thus the other end of each resistor is also at an equal (not same as before) electric potential.

2 or more resistors are connected in parallel if the p.d across them is the same. THis means that the 4 resistors are in parallel with eachother